# Why isn't my angular directive pulling in this attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes

This is undefined, but I am not sure why?
 Directive:

```
<input type="password" float-placeholder
       custom-error="test" placeholder="Confirm password"
       required name="passwordSecond" id="passwordSecond"
       ng-model="vs.PasswordSecond" />
```

```
angular.module('inMyBag').directive('floatPlaceholder', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      customError: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('blur', function() {
        console.log(scope.customError);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This is in `angular 1.6`.

Comment: Because it interprets `test` as a variable. If you want to pass the string "test", then surround it with ' single-quotes. LIke this
custom-error=" 'test' " (the space chars are for readability)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but do you have any idea why when I update the attribute it doesn't change the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind attribute text to scope, use attribute `@` binding:

```
app.directive('floatPlaceholder', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ̶c̶u̶s̶t̶o̶m̶E̶r̶r̶o̶r̶:̶ ̶̶̶'̶̶̶=̶̶̶'̶̶̶ 
      customError: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('blur', function() {
        console.log(scope.customError);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Directive inputs use `<` and `@` bindings. The `<` symbol denotes [one-way bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) which are available since 1.5. Attribute `@` bindings can be used when the input is a string, especially when the value of the binding doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but when I update the attribute the value doesn't change. Any ideas how I can solve that?

Comment: signupForm.passwordSecond.setAttribute('custom-error', _this.Error);

Comment: DOM manipulation should be encapsulated in [custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and need to be integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. I need to understand the entire context to write a proper answer. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For information on writing directives for custom validation, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Modifying Built-in Validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#modifying-built-in-validators).

Comment: See my new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634850/passing-information-to-directive

Answer (score 0):

You already have some suggestions in comments, but need to add, that you better have to use `on()` instead of `bind()`, because the `bind()` is deprecated. Screenshot from docs:

[image]

And the link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

And why don't you use [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)?