# Passing Information to Directive to Match Passwords

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-form

I'm trying to add an errors to my floating placeholder labels when certain conditions are met in my controller

However, I'm not sure the best way to go about this and my current implementing doesn't seem to be detecting the attribute change in the directive (custom-error stays set to "test").

Here's what I've got right now:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="password" float-placeholder
       custom-error="test" placeholder="Confirm password"
       required name="passwordSecond" id="passwordSecond"
       ng-model="vs.PasswordSecond" />
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('floatPlaceholder', function ($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      customError: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.after("<label class='floating-placeholder'>" + attrs.placeholder + "</label>");
      var label = angular.element(ele.parent()[0].getElementsByClassName('floating-placeholder'));

      element.on('blur', function() {
        if (ele.val().length > 0) { 
          if (scope.customError) {
            label.text(attrs.placeholder + ' - ' + scope.customError);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SignupController', function factory() {
  _this.confirmPassword = () => {
    if(_this.PasswordFirst !== _this.PasswordSecond){
      angular.element(signupForm.passwordSecond).attr('custom-error', _this.Error);
    }
  }
});
```

I'm using Angular 1.6

Comment: Code is in bits, please give a working demo highlighting the issue. I'm try to recreate but some variables are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Validator Directive which Matches Passwords

To have a [form](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) match password inputs, create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that hooks into the [ngModelController API ($validators)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators):

```
app.directive("matchWith", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: postLink
  };
  function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
    ngModel.$validators.match = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ngModel.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }
        var matchValue = scope.$eval(attrs.matchWith);
        if (matchValue == modelValue) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }
        // it is invalid
        return false;
    };
  }
})
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms - Modifying Built-in Validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#modifying-built-in-validators)

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/jP8sYp0ybIzJOLJkA0HY?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("matchWith", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: postLink
  };
  function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
    ngModel.$validators.match = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ngModel.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }
        var matchValue = scope.$eval(attrs.matchWith);
        if (matchValue == modelValue) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }
        // it is invalid
        return false;
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <form name="form1">
        <input type="password" name="password1" required
               placeholder="Enter password"
               ng-model="vm.password1" />
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password2" required
               placeholder="Confirm password"
               ng-model="vm.password2"
               match-with="vm.password1"
               ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
        <br>
        <p ng-show="form1.password2.$error.match">
          Passwords don't match
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at your code. Have you defined the scope variables in the SignUpController

_this.PasswordFirst and _this.PasswordSecond

Also this line in your controller

angular.element(signupForm.passwordSecond).attr('custom-error', _this.Error);

good suggestion would be to implement this in the directive as attributes can be accessed correctly in the directive

Answer (score 0):

(I'm basing this on you saying 'custom-error stays set to "test"')

custom-error is looking for a variable of "test", not a string value of "test". Have you tried setting a variable test in your controller and updating that?